# C# executable linux Mint

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have a few console apps that I want to run on a dedicated box.  However, I have no interest in purchasing a windows license.

Is there anything special I have to do after compiling the code to run on linux mint?

Comment: You do realize how generic this is, right? Without more knowledge about the program (libraries used, any calls off to native methods, etc) it's impossible to say.

Comment: i tried just executing it, as far as libraries and all the only thing I'm really referencing is html agilitypack and mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you'd install mono

```
http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/mono-runtime
http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/mono-complete
```

The most popular package for developers seems to be

```
http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/monodevelop
```

With existing console applications, there will be no need to recompile (.NET is platform indepent, remember?). However, there could be slight incompatibilities to missing support for very specific Microsoft Class libraries (think of WPF, till recently Message Queues, some Winforms Stuff and obvious Interop (P/Invokes of native libraries).

[Use the Moma tool to scan for such incompatibilities](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), and you'll get a nice overview of things that *might* cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just compile your code using the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) compiler and you should be good, if it's a simple console app.

Comment: No need to compile. Just run the binaries on Linux using mono

Comment: @sehe: You're right; I guess I was thinking from the perspective of doing it from the ground up (i.e., including development) all within Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Mono installed on the Linux box and you don't use anything MS-specific, then no, you don't have to do anything special. Just compile the .exe, copy it to the linux box and run it using `mono the_app.exe`.